# configure: error: png.h not found while compiling php-5.2.8 on SLES-12-64bit LINUX

Tags: php, linux, apache, libpng, sles

I am compiling php-5.2.8 on SLES-12-64bit LINUX.
I am getting below error after running configure script.

**configure: error: png.h not found.**

I have also installed libpng16-devel, see the below command output,

# rpm -qa | grep -i libpng

libpng16-16-32bit-1.6.8-2.24.x86_64

libpng16-16-1.6.8-2.24.x86_64

libpng16-devel-32bit-1.6.8-2.2.x86_64

libpng16-devel-1.6.8-2.2.x86_64

# ls -l  /usr/include/libpng16/png.h

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 149224 Sep 11 13:40 /usr/include/libpng16/png.h

Below are the options provided by me to configure script,
./configure

```
    --prefix=/opt/MicroWorld/usr \
    --exec-prefix=/opt/MicroWorld/usr \
    --sysconfdir=/opt/MicroWorld/etc/httpd/php5 \
    --sharedstatedir=/opt/MicroWorld/usr/php5 \
    --libdir=/opt/MicroWorld/usr/lib/mwhttpd/php5 \
    --includedir=/opt/MicroWorld/usr/include/php5 \
    --with-apache=../apache_1.3.41 \
    --with-config-file-path=/opt/MicroWorld/etc/httpd/php5 \
    --enable-magic-quotes \
    --without-pear \
    --enable-memory-limit \
    --disable-rpath \
    --enable-sockets \
    --with-ldap \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --enable-fpm \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-debug \
    --with-gd \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-dmalloc \
    --with-tsrm-pthreads \
    --enable-cli \
    --disable-cgi \
    --enable-inline-optimization \
    --enable-ftp \
    --enable-magic-quotes \
    --enable-calendar \
    --enable-bcmath \
    --enable-exif \
    --with-mod_charset \
    --enable-safe-mode \
    --enable-sigchild \
    --enable-dbx \
    --enable-dbase \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --disable-libxml \
    --disable-simplexml \
    --disable-xml \
    --disable-xmlreader \
    --disable-xmlwriter \
    --disable-dom \
    --enable-pthreads=static \
    --enable-pcntl \
    --enable-maintainer-zts \
    --with-gettext=/usr/local \
    --with-zlib \
    --with-libdir=lib64 \
    --with-png-dir=/usr/include/libpng16 \
    --with-jpeg-dir
```

Any help to solve this problem is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The software you're trying to compile here — PHP 5.2.8 with Apache 1.3.41 — is all *ancient*. PHP 5.2.8 was released in December 2008, and Apache 1.3.41 was released in January 2008. Please tell me you're building this software for purely historical purposes?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a Debian variant, try this :

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Then, you should install the "...-headers" part of the library the configure scripts complains it doesn't have (namely : png.h).
To find it using CLI :

`apt-cache search png | grep -i header`

If you're using Redhat, I guess a little googling can get you the equivalent command lines :)

Comment: Should be `build-essential` not `build-essentials`

Answer (score 1):

---

Suse "12" : Search for libpng → → `# zypper se libpng`

Install the devel package : `# zypper in libpng12-compat-devel`

Or : `# zypper in libpng14-devel`

---